# countdown timer loader animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Circle outline completes before timer finish. Although it is working fine when with the larger circle. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz32sy7y/2832/)

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1

/* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('h2').text(i);
  if (i == time) {   
      clearInterval(interval);
   return;
    }
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; 
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="70" height="70" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="25" cy="35" cx="35" stroke-width="4" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="#ccc"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to set `time` dinamiclly according the shape size?

Comment: Try to set `var time = 1;` to this small circle

Answer (score 2):

You have to reduce the offset, both in css and javascript, i updated your code there :
http://jsfiddle.net/3recj0s9/

CSS :

```
.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 155; 
  stroke-dashoffset: 155;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

JS

```
var initialOffset = '155';
```